# Material Design windowBackground

Tags: android, colors, android-studio, material-design

I'm trying to customize the colors in the test app I'm building while adhering to the Material Design specifications.

Based on figure 3 here, https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html one of the attributes I'm supposed to be using is android:windowBackground. When I try to use this to set the background color in the app I get an error stating "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowBackground'." What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify `android:windowBackground` with Material theme.
This is how it could look like for v21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="windowBackground">#1A237E</color>

    <style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#00BCD4</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`android:windowBackground` attribute is from API level 1, so you should always refer it this way for any target and min SDK levels.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information from that page:

> Note: The material theme is only available in Android 5.0 (API level
>   21) and above. The v7 Support Libraries provide themes with material
>   design styles for some widgets and support for customizing the color
>   palette. For more information, see Maintaining Compatibility.

To include the v7 Support Library in your app add `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+` to your app build.gradle file dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented the v7 support library in the app as you have recommended, yet I still get this error.

Comment: Also, in values-v21, do I need to use material theme as parent? Currently I'm using appcompatv7 as parent for both values-v21 and the standard values styles.xml. I want to be able to use the them material.dark but I've been unable to do so and have had to use appcompatv7.

Comment: Make sure your theme looks like this:

`<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">*put the color in here*</item
</style>`

Comment: Does Android 5.0 accept it in the format of "android:" or is it just "windowBackground"?

Comment: For Android 5.0 the item name needs to be `android:windowBackground` but I would put the style as `android:Theme.Material.Light`